# Next Post Link in format

Tags: post-formats, next-post-link

I'm after a wordpress function that can give me the link to the next post with the same format as the current post. I've been looking and struggling to find one.

I expected to find an option similar to the `in_same_cat` option from the `next/prev_post_link` function.

Anyone know of one I don't or have other options on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What does "with the same format" mean? You just want results in the same category/taxonomy/something?

Comment: There is an "in_same_cat" argument for `next_post_link`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link I am more confused now.

Comment: Posts can have both a category and [a format](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) (video, image, status etc) I thought there would be a way to navigate between them in the same way that you can with category.

Comment: Ok. Got it. You are talking about post formats. This could be tricky.